# Make [java.lang] a synonym of [java]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

`java.lang` is just the name of the base package which is imported by default into every Java file. So I don't think that the [java.lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.lang) tag adds anymore information than simply specifiying [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).<sup>1</sup>

So I propose to just make [java.lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.lang) a synonym of [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

---

<sup>[1] I also don't think that it means to reference java as a language like some other [`*-lang` tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*-lang) that we have.</sup>

Comment: It seems like a mistake. Looking at the usages, a lot of questions related to errors use it, probably solely because they reference java.lang.IllegalStateException or java.lang.nullpointerexception or java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError etc. So the tag clarifies exactly nothing about the question. It may as well has been tagged with [problem]...it might even be a slightly more descriptive tag. I don't see any reason to have a specific tag for java.lang.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### These tags have now been merged as described below.

---

#### Analysis

Of the 65 questions, there are only 3 that actually ask about the `java.lang` package in any meaningful sense:

- [Why I am able to re-create java.lang package and classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116767/why-i-am-able-to-re-create-java-lang-package-and-classes)
- [Is java.lang.Math compatible with kotlin.math?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49347692/is-java-lang-math-compatible-with-kotlin-math)
- [Java: How to Exclude Implicit Import of java.lang classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465651/java-how-to-exclude-implicit-import-of-java-lang-classes)

That's 1) not very many in an absolute sense, and 2) a really tiny percentage of the tag's actual usage.

Further, all three would be (and, in fact, already are) correctly tagged [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

The rest are just questions involving some class (usually an Exception) in `java.lang`, which, given how core those classes are to the language, would be basically any [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) question, as well as any question in pretty much every other JVM language that uses the Java standard library.  That wouldn't be a useful tag, given that tagging those languages would adequately convey the same information (well, Kotlin is a little weird here since it supports both JVM and non-JVM targets, but also this would not be the way to handle that over something like a [kotlin-jvm] tag, if that were desired).

#### Recommendation

Merge [java.lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.lang) into [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).  Don't create a synonym.  3 questions in 7 years isn't enough to justify a tag this easily misused.

Comment: My initial reaction was "no this isn't a synonym".  But the `java.lang` tag doesn't need to exist. So assuming "merge but don't synonym" means we'll see everything `java` and nothing `java.lang` I'm a +1.

Comment: I like this idea a lot. Merging in this case is an untraceable retagging from `java.lang` to `java`, right? I agree that a synonym is not used, we just don't want this tag anymore.

Comment: @Lino that's correct. We have the option to merge when creating a synonym.  Afterward, we can remove the original tag, which will have the effect of replacing it on all questions that had it without creating any revision history entries on the questions.

Answer (score 3):

I can import `java.lang.Double` from within a Kotlin application, or from a Clojure application.

Do not conflate the libraries and packages of Java with it being *exclusively* limited to Java.

But also too, this tag is kinda...*meh*.  When people ask a question about Java, and they're asking a question about something in `java.lang`, there's a *very* good chance that they're asking something about a *specific* class within that.  There's an even *better* chance that they're going to ask a specific question with a specific JVM language, too.

So honestly I'd recommend *blacklisting* `java.lang`.  People need to ask questions in regards to specific classes and specific JVM technologies.

Comment: I proposed the synonym because I know that it's easier to accomplish. As blacklisting (AFAIK) includes dev time. Another possibility would be to "simply" burn the tag, and then see in the future if it resurfaces again, which I assume will happen... Regarding the usage *outside* of Java, I still think that the synonym would be valid. You use something from Java so you may as well tag it with `[java]`, even though your question is about Groovy or Kotlin or whatever

Comment: You might, you might not, depends on the context of what you're asking.  But to be honest don't be discouraged by the thought that some action needs dev time; if it's the more ideal action to take, then the resource issue can be resolved at a later point.

Comment: @Lino: Blocking a tag does require a dev to do it, but it's generally only done if the tag has been previously burninated and then been recreated, as you suggest doing. (And even then, the community usually has to burninate the tag again before the devs can block it.) That said, I'm not suggesting which course of action y'all should take – just explaining the process :)